# Create outlook profile using vb.net or powershell or cmd

Tags: vb.net, powershell, outlook, user-profile

I've got to reconfigure 300 user profiles in the next week or two, changing their outlook from looking at the current exchange server to a new one outside of the AD.

These users are at various sites around the country and it's a logistical nightmare to do manually.

What I would like to do is write a little app which checks the logged on user, matches them in my database to grab their details, then automatically creates the mail profile for outlook to use for that user.

I know how to do the first and second steps, but creating the mail profile I have no idea how to do.

I've had a google and there doesn't seem to be much info about doing this programatically... can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction?

Even if this can be done in powershell or commandprompt that would do, as I can dynamically write that script per user before it is run.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using Group Policy for this?

Comment: What have you tried? What have you done? Show us your script and ideas so that we can help you, not write it for you.

Comment: So far I dont have a script... I've googled around looking for ideas on how to achieve this.

I know how to grab the logged on user and I know how to match them in my mysql db via the net to retrieve the details needed for the profile, but i have absolutely no idea how to go about creating the profile.

As for not using gp... the domain the users are currently on is not my domain. We're going through a migration process now, bringing the users over to ourselves. They will be going live in a few months, but due to their current exchange having now room left, I need to migrate that now.

Answer (score 0):

Profiles can be created using Extended MAPI only (C++ or Delphi) - see [IProfAdmin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815345.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) interface. You can see that interface in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - click IProfAdmin button.

In case of a language other than C++ or Delphi, you can use the [ProfMan](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman.htm) library (I am its author, it ships with the distributable version of [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption), which I also authored). There are a few example on how to create profiles and add different MAPI services at http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman_examples.htm